# Nearby convex set in a nearby space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convexity, alexandrov-geometry

Let $K$ be a convex set in a [CAT(0) space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_space) $X$. Suppose $X'$ is a CAT(0) space that is *very close* to $X$.

> Is there a convex set $K'\subset X'$ that is *close* to $K\subset X$?

Two spaces $X$ and $X'$ are *$a$-close* if there is a homeomorphism $\iota\colon X\to X'$ that changes metric by at most $a$.
Two subsets $K\subset X$ and $K'\subset X'$ are *$b$-close* if the Hausdorff distance between $\iota(K)$ and $K'$ in $X'$ is at most $b$.

**Comments.**

- I suspect that the answer is "no".
- I do not know the answer even if $X$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
- If $X=\mathbb{R}^3$, then the answer is "yes"; it is easy.
- I also do not know the answer if $X$ is a Lobachevsky space.
- The motivation comes from the [question about the compactness of convex hull in CAT(0)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6627/convex-hull-in-cat0).

Comment: a somewhat similar question in the linear category https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379018/if-a-subspace-f-is-contained-in-a-subspace-g-and-h-is-close-to-g-can-w